# error with surf.get_at() pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a game and I need to know what colour is under the player's feet but when I use `surf.get_at_(x, y)`, it gives me white instead of blue or green.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Remember, you need to use get_at on the surface that has the color. For example, you could do `screen.get_at(x,y)` or `player.get_at(x,y)`. Also, make sure that you are doing this **after** things have been drawn on the surface. If you do `screen.fill([255,255,255])` and then immediately try to `screen.get_at(x,y)` it **will** always return white, because the whole surface is white!

Answer (score 0):

The argument for `get_at()` must be a tuple with the coordinate pair. See to documentation of [`pygame.Surface.get_at`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at):

> get the color value at a single pixel
>
> ```
> get_at((x, y)) -> Color
> ```

Use a tuple with the coordinates instead of two separate arguments:

<s>`surf.get_at_(x, y)`</s>

```py
surf.get_at_((x, y))
```